# No cached date in Google cache for PDF files

Tags: google, google-search, pdf, google-cache

Google displays no cache date in their cached version of PDF files. Does somebody know any way to determine when a certain PDF file was cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a comment by Matt Cutts, former head of the web spam team at Google:

> **my guess is that it wouldn’t be trivial to add crawl dates to PDF, but I’ll ask.**
>
> *[Video: Crawl dates in the Google cache - Matt Cutts](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/video-crawl-dates-in-the-google-cache/)*

I know it's not the answer you were looking for, but it seems like there may be a technical reason that Google doesn't keep track of the cached date for PDF files.